# Google Spreadsheets. Paste data from one range to another if title and sub-title are equal

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two ranges...

**Range1**:

```txt
|Year |2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2024|2024|2024|
|Month|  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |  1 |  2 |  3 |
|Value|  0 |  0 | 100|  0 |  0 | 200|  0 | 100|  0 |
```

**Range2**:

```txt
|Year |2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2024|2024|2024|2024|2024|2024|
|Month|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |
|Value|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

I need to paste values from `Range1` to `Range2` if year and month is the same. So it will look like...

**Expected Results**:

```txt
|Year |2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2023|2024|2024|2024|2024|2024|2024|
|Month|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |
|Value|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 100|  0 |  0 | 200|  0 | 100|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

If I change month in `Range1` it changes accordingly in the result range.

Thanks!!!

I tried myself using filter, lookup, even chatGPT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the `hlookup`

```
=index(ifna(hlookup(B8:Y8&B9:Y9,{B1:J1&B2:J2;B3:J3},2,),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply the hlookup is definetly what I need there. But I'm not sure why it doesn't work, probably I because of references insted of fixed numbers. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZubnfEtdgBf0u7ckKVDjvN0_dl5FTQX-JpZ6e2OSKXY/edit#gid=0
I'm talking about rows 332 333 346 369 370 388

Comment: done.. updated the above formula in your sheet